# Is there any way to create a POST HTTP request using window.location?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, ejs

I have a web app built using node and express, and there is a form I want to submit in an ejs file, but I cannot use `form.submit()` because I want to pass parameters in the URL.

The form's id is `"update"` and the submit buttons id is `"btnsubmit"`, I am currently trying to send the post request as follows:

```
var form = document.getElementById("update");
document.getElementById("btnsubmit").addEventListener("click", function () {
  var lp = "1";
  window.location = ("/dbinsertupdateditem?loadpage="+encodeURIComponent(lp));
});
```

On button click I get the error: `Cannot GET /dbinsertupdateditem`, because the express route is expecting a POST request. Is it possible to make a POST request with window.location or do I need to go about a different way of solving this?

Comment: No, window.location.href is a GET. You need need to post a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not change how window.location.href works. As a result, you need post a form if the router expects it to be a post. If you have a form on the page you can just set the action

```
var form = document.getElementById("update");
form.action = "/dbinsertupdateditem?loadpage="+encodeURIComponent(lp);
form.submit();
```

If you do not have a form, create one

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.method = "POST";
form.action = "/dbinsertupdateditem?loadpage="+encodeURIComponent(lp);
document.body.append(form);
form.submit();
```

Or probably the best answer, change your backend to allow GET

Comment: Awesome that works thank you. If I were to change the backend to allow GET would I still be able to access the ```request.body``` that is sent when the HTTP POST request is made??